# Is it guaranteed that all the stages in a Jenkins pipeline will get executed on same host?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If I have a jenkins pipeline which is restricted to get executed on a specific label (say `label1`) which has two or three machines/hosts/nodes (ex: host1,host2..) that are linked with it. say I've `build`,`lint` and `test` stages in Jenkinsfile and when the job triggered and it started executing the job on host/node `host1`. Is it guaranteed that jenkins will finish this job on same host/node `host1` with all the stages(build, lint ..) in the job? or it does switch to other hosts/nodes in between the stages(build, lint ..)?

```
pipeline {

    agent {
       label 'label1'
    }


    stages {
       stage('build') {
           steps {
               sh('echo build')
           }
       }

       stage('lint') {
            steps {
               sh ('echo lint')
            }
       }

       stage('test') {
            steps {
               sh ('echo test')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you explicitly define a different agent in a stage (which is possible) all your stages will be run on the same executor. Which makes sense: It would be a really inconvenient overhead if you had to declare the agent in every stage to keep it the same.